# How to draw regression line in a graph

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I am exploring machine learning and got to know about regression. But, I did not understand how the regression line is plotted after marking the points. I searched stack overflow but, found only codes to draw the line. I want to know on what basis the line is drawn.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Least squares method is used for drawing regression line.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares

Comment: Found a better explanation than Wikipedia https://youtu.be/JvS2triCgOY